# Cannot disable Intel RST, what should I do?

Tags: rst

I have an Acer Predator Triton 700 and it does not have option to disable Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology) in the BIOS. What should I do?

Comment: Hello. Why do you want to do this? You question needs a ton more details. If you are trying to install Ubuntu what version is it?

Comment: Acer hides the function. When you're in your BIOS on the main page, press [Ctrl]+[S]. Then you will see the option to change RST to AHCI.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply but I have already tried [Ctrl]+[S].It doesn't work even sent to Acer service centre and they said it can't be done.

Comment: Ubuntu I am trying to install is 20.04.1 desktop.When trying to install it gives error to disable Intel RST.

Comment: If it is not a dual boot, then RST is not a problem. In case of a dual boot, you may need to re-install Windows.